# How can I update an existing DOM element in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cropperjs

I am using cropper.js tool to get screen shots from a PDF file. I'd like to customize the crop box tool - i.e. Add some custom buttons at the bottom of the crop box. When loading the PDF file, cropper.js creates some DOM element. It contains the cropper tools. One of them is a div with class name of 'cropper-crop-box'. I am trying to add a new div containing some buttons with the code below:

```
btnGroup = React.createElement('div', { className: 'cropper-button-group d-flex justify-content-center align-content-center' }, [
            React.createElement('button', { key: '123', className: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary cropper-select-answer me-1', onClick: () => selectAnswer('A') }, 'A'),
            React.createElement('button', { key: '456', className: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary cropper-select-answer me-1', onClick: () => selectAnswer('B') }, 'B'),
            React.createElement('button', { key: '789', className: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary cropper-select-answer me-1', onClick: () => selectAnswer('C') }, 'C'),
            React.createElement('button', { key: '012', className: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary cropper-select-answer me-1', onClick: () => selectAnswer('D') }, 'D'),
            React.createElement('button', { key: '345', className: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary cropper-select-answer me-1', onClick: () => selectAnswer('E') }, 'E'),
            React.createElement('button', { key: '678', className: 'btn btn-sm btn-success cropper-select-image me-1', onClick: () => doCrop() }, <FaCrop size={14} color='white' />),
            React.createElement('button', { key: '901', className: 'btn btn-sm btn-danger cropper-select-image', onClick: () => cancelCrop() }, <FaCrop size={14} color='white' />),
    ])
    const el = document.createElement('div')
    el.innerHTML = renderToString(btnGroup)
    document.getElementsByClassName("cropper-crop-box")[0].append(el.firstChild)
```

The buttons are added but onClick event aren't working. If I try the code below, the existing content of the div is gone. Only buttons are visible:

```
const container = document.getElementsByClassName("cropper-crop-box")[0]
    container.innerHtml = renderToString(btnGroup)
    const root = createRoot(container)
    root.render(btnGroup)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Is there only ever *one* crop box tool in the page? And that element is completely outside the control of your React code? (Also, your second code block has `innerHtml`, not `innerHTML`.)

Comment: Yes only one. That element is completely outside of my React code.

Comment: When I said 'That element is completely outside of my React code', I wished to mean that DOM elements are created by cropper.js dynamically, not by React but they are in the root element controlled by React.

Comment: Yup, that was clear, thanks. :-)

Comment: New buttons' container must be in 'container = document.getElementsByClassName("cropper-crop-box")'. It resides in the root div and dynamically created by cropperjs.

Comment: `const root = createRoot(container) root.render(btnGroup)` This code causes the existing content to disappear. That's the problem I try to solve.

Comment: I've updated my answer below to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's only *one* `.cropper-crop-box` element on the page, you can do this in React via a [portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html). A portal lets you have a component's content rendered to an arbitrary DOM element instead of the component's parent element. Here's a simple example:

```js
const { useState } = React;

// You might want to memoize a component like this (see
// `React.memo`), but I didn't here in order to show that
// the portal is updated in place.
const CropBoxButtons = () => {
    // Get the element we render our custom content to, creating it if we
    // haven't added it yet.
    const cropBox = document.querySelector(".cropper-crop-box");
    if (!cropBox) {
        throw new Error("Can't find .cropper-crop-box element");
    }
    // I'd probably use ?? instead of || below, but the old version of Babel
    // in Stack Snippets doesn't support it
    const cropBoxCustomContent =
        cropBox.querySelector(".custom-content") ||
        document.createElement("div");
    if (!cropBoxCustomContent.parentElement) {
        cropBoxCustomContent.classList.add("custom-content");
        cropBox.appendChild(cropBoxCustomContent);
    }

    const selectA = () => console.log("Select A");
    const selectB = () => console.log("Select B");
    const selectC = () => console.log("Select C");

    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
        // Unfortunately, Stack Snippets don't support the more concise
        // <>...</> shorthand for fragments
        <React.Fragment>
            <input type="button" value="Select A" onClick={selectA} />
            <input type="button" value="Select B" onClick={selectB} />
            <input type="button" value="Select C" onClick={selectC} />
        </React.Fragment>,
        cropBoxCustomContent
    );
};

const Example = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    return <div>
        <div>
            This is stuff in the usual React app part of things. Here's a button to update
            state to show it works:
        </div>
        <input
            type="button"
            value="+"
            onClick={() => setCounter((c) => c + 1)}
        /> Clicks: {counter}
        <CropBoxButtons />
    </div>;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```css
.custom-content {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- The usual React root -->
<div id="root"></div>

<!-- A stand-in for the crop box tool -->
<div class="cropper-crop-box">
    <h2>Crop Box</h2>
    <input type="button" value="Built-In Button">
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: New div and buttons should be in `<div id="root"></div>`. Can I use createPortal to accomplish this too?

Comment: @MuratTopçu - If they should be there, aren't they just part of your normal React app?

Comment: I am using react-pdf library to view a pdf on canvas. With cropper.js I am creating a crop tool on that PDF view. This tool is created by Vanilla JS. I can create the buttons in that tool with Vanilla JS but their onClick events aren't working. When I use root.render after creation buttons' events are working but nothing other than buttons are left on the div.

Comment: PDF viewer is handled by React but crop tool not.

Comment: @MuratTopçu - The above shows you how to put buttons in an element that is outside your React app's primary element, with click handlers that work.

Comment: Yeah I understand and appreciate your support. How can this scenario be accomplished inside React app's primary element?